# Using Watir How can i visit all the links of a web page and then sub links of the visited link

Tags: watir

strong textI have a web page that is containing several links on it, and when we click on any link it redirect to another page that is also containing several links, like wise all links have several pages.
I want to click on all the links and when i click on first link script should click on all the links of redirected page and so on.. when it done the clicking on the links, again second links link of the first page should get clicked like wise for links.

Please any one can help me on this, I have developed the script by which I am able to click on all the links of main(first) page but not getting idea how to do that for sub pages of the application.
Please revert ASAP, its very urgent.

Comment: Please provide code that you have so far.

Comment: Are the links on each page static (ie fixed URL and always displayed) or dynamic (eg on StackOverflow, the list of questions always has a link to a question, but the URL would be different (ie to a different question) depending on when you look at the list)?

Comment: All the links on page are static, always available

Answer (score 2):

You just have to implement some recursive function like this:

```
def crawl(link)
  browser.goto link

  # gather all links before navigating to next link
  all_links = browser.links.reduce([]) do |memo, link|
    memo << link if link.href =~ /appdomain/ # do not visit external links
    memo
  end

  all_links.each do |link|
    crawl link
  end
end

crawl "http://appdomain.com/"
```

This is untested code, but it might work :)

Also this code does not avoid clicking link to same path twice from different places - there's room for optimization.

It might be that you're using wrong tool for your job - at least it seems so when reading your question. What is the original problem?